# How do I show formatted numbers only in the formatted form in Excel cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So when I am using excel, sometimes a formula used will prompt an answer such as 67.9999999.

When I then paste this into another cell which I have formatted to  2 decimal places it shows 68, but in the top formula bar it will still show it as 67.99999.

How am I able to change this without manually going through each one and rewriting it in the 2 decimal place format, so both the cell and the formula bar now reflect the 2 decimal place number?

Thankyou

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: If you format a cell to show two decimal places, it will show 67.99999 as 68.00, not 68.  If you want both the cell and the formula bar to reflect two decimal places, or whatever, you will need to change your formula to use the `ROUND` function.

Comment: You could also use `Precision as Displayed`, but his will permanently reduce precision throughout the entire workbook.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was a bad example on my part, I meant 18.00 but what I ultimately meant was making whatever was in the cell, exactly the same as what was in the formula bar.  So If I use the "Precision as Displayed" will this then show the two as being exactly the same? And permanent reducing doesn't matter because I will be copying only that value, so the figures won't be used in any other calculations. I am using the latest version of excel, so will this then work?

Comment: @FionaAppleton, the wording in your comment is confusing relative to the question.  You want the cell display and formula bar to match; the question is which to use for the basis.  Just to confirm, you want the formula bar to be based on what's displayed in the cell, not the other way around, right?

Comment: That is correct. To put it another way, I have spreadsheet A that has values on it that are formatted to two decimal places, but if you click into the cell it will show in the formula bar the full number. I want to copy and paste those values into spreadsheet B which will show the value in the cell the same as before BUT also showing that same thing in the formula bar, so they match. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @FionaAppleton  No they will not necessarily match exactly.  For example, if your value is `68`, but your cell is formatted with two decimals, the cell will show `68.00` and the formula bar will show `68`.  Unless you convert all your values to Text, and format the cell as text, there is no way to accomplish what you want.  What is the purpose of this requirement?

Comment: Because I have spreadsheet A with a lot of values on it (that have values such as 68 but in the formula bar 67.9999 or whatever) and normally I am supposed to then input these numbers manually onto spreadsheet B. Just manually inputting "68" will of course show that both in the cell and the formula bar. But recently the spreadsheet I take these values from has got much bigger so there is a lot more to do. So, I am looking for a way to copy/paste these values while still making them look as neat as when they are inputted manually, without the time consuming aspect of it.

Comment: Hide the formula bar.

Comment: That isn't really an option, other people need to be able to access the spreadsheet.

Comment: Consider a "middle ground".  I understand your issue with 67.99999 vs. 68, they look like different numbers.  However, most people would see 68 and 68.00 as the same number with different formatting.  Can you live with that type of difference?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical example of the value displayed in the cell  not matching the value in the Formula Bar:

[image]

Note the cell format is **General**

Select the cells like this that you want to fix and run this short macro:

```
Sub FixData()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = r.Text
    Next r
End Sub
```

to yield:

[image]

*(the macro make no attempt to adjust the format of the cell)*

Comment: Thankyou for this, but do you have a way of doing it that doesn't involve using macro's or anything similar? I can't have anything on the spreadsheet that looks like it has been "tampered" with, I was hoping that between spreadsheet A and B (which are accessible to lots of people) I could paste the information from spreadsheet A onto my own spreadsheet, make it so it matches and THEN post that onto spreadsheet B, so it leaves no show, just like it was all inputted manually. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Copy the data from the public spreadsheet (at a time when no one has it open and might modify it before you paste the corrected data back in!) into your spreadsheet in some convenient place. If it is a spreadsheet you use only for this purpose, or one you just open New, do the work, then close without ever saving, that'd be best:  either of those two choices.

Once it is there with all the decimal places it came with, write a formula in a column nearby like the following:

```
=ROUND( DATA, 2)
```

`ROUND()` will change each value to two decimal places in the same manner Excel uses when choosing how to display it showing only two decimal places.

Copy the cell down matching the column of data you copied in. You now have a column of values rounded to two decimal places that matches the displayed values in the public spreadsheet.

Copy that range of cells. Go back to the public spreadsheet and `Paste | Special | Values` overtop the original data cells. They are now replaced with the same value that Excel was showing.

If you aren't familiar with `Paste | Special | Values`, there are many ways to make it happen, but the easiest is to use a shortcut key combination. I use a different one that is hard to explain here, but for many years used `Alt-E-S-V`, then pressing `Enter`. ANY way you know how to do it though, the end result is happiness.

You still have the original values in the throwaway spreadsheet so take a quick look that nothing funky happened. If it all looks good, save it and then close the throwaway spreadsheet. If it looks funky though, try to figure out why, but then either just close the public spreadsheet WITHOUT saving (you can always start completely over, eh?), press `Ctrl-Z`, or copy the original data back over the stuff you just pasted in. Three good ways to make sure an unhappy bit of work goes away leaving you the original.

The key is that you are willing, as you say above, to do the "copy it over, fix it, copy it back" work. If something makes that impossible (like... the public spreadsheet is never closed by all possible users for long enough for you to do this), then this method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone with the same need (I don't think `Fiona Appleton` will be reading this answer after five years!), might get value from the answer I gave to:

[Decimals still in formula bar view (not in cell view) - need to round and remove](https://superuser.com/questions/1679371/decimals-still-in-formula-bar-view-not-in-cell-view-need-to-round-and-remove/1679418#1679418)

which asks a similar question.

It is VERY similar, but different so pasting it here would not really suit, exactly. It basically explains the gains and losses from `Precision As Displayed` to help someone choose to use it or not based on their situation. It points out there are some VBA approaches and the other answer to that question gives one of those solutions. It also has a method for exporting the data in the form needed (exporting it so is the need in the other question, but it doesn't seem so here so that might not be of any use at all). It also mentions the downside to hiding the formula editor if one's goal is that the users NEVER see the precise values, only the displayed values, but that wouldn't matter if one only needed to not rub the precise values in their faces.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1082778)