# Decimals still in formula bar view (not in cell view) - need to round and remove

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an ID (number format) that has trailing decimals in the source data. I need to retain the rounded number (see example attached) and have the trailing decimals removed from the data. The decimals are causing upload issues/error into a system that I use.

I have tried formatting to number and removing decimal places, =INT, =ROUND, etc and I can get the cell view to reflect what I want but when I click on the cell, the formula bar still appears to retain the trailing decimals. How do I remove these? Thanks in advance!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Use VBA.

1. Press ALT+F11, to open VBA editor.
2. On the menu, click Tools -> References. Add "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5", then click OK.

[image]

3. Add the following code:

```vb
Sub SetToInteger()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    'Get last row with value of column A
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            
    'Loop through the values
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        Range("A" & i).Value = Int(Range("A" & i).Value)
    Next i

End Sub
```

4. Press F5 to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

VBA can do it, of course, in several ways, some easier than the other answer's method.

After telling you "the" way to do it, I will tell you another thought that is based upon what you exactly wrote in your question. If it can be used, it's the easiest and best of any ideas.

So, if you want a "pure" Excel method, you could use a feature called `Precision As Displayed".

To save time for you, if you ONLY want a set of cells to do this, but want OTHER cells to perform normally, their decimal portions not REMOVED in this manner — in other words, you have mixed needs in regards to this in the whole spreadsheet as this affects the whole thing, not just a worksheet, **STOP** right now as this will not let you have both kinds of behavior. It is the following, or it is the usual behavior you encounter in Excel... NOT BOTH.

`Precision As Displayed` ("PAD" from now on) will let you enter a value, but then after applying the number formatting choice you have made, it not only displays the entry as formatted, it also PERMANENTLY CHANGES the entry to what you see.

So if you set the format to be the integer portion only, Excel will do that like normally including using rounding the same way you normally would see it do, but then would permanently, destructively (the original entry will be completely replaced by this), replaces the actual entry with the exact displayed value.

Then anyone looking in the formula editing bar would not see the decimal portion of the entry as it would be gone. Not hidden:  gone.

This also means that a reference to the cell value would return exactly that as well. So someone could not be slick — write a quick formula like "=A1" and see the original entry — because it doesn't exist anymore.

If you can have that happen everywhere in the spreadsheet, it will work nicely for you. But if you have to have the usual behavior as well, it will not do you any good at all.

You can do a couple other things including blanking the formula editing bar, but they retain the original entries so those are then used in downstream calculations and they also can be viewed with the simple "=A1" kind of formula.

If curious as to why the setting exists, it's for backwards compatibility with 35 year old spreadsheets... seriously... and it is also useful for when you want interim calculations to be used as they display without layering rounding functions on everything. Payroll, for example. Calculate Social Security's retirement tax, say, and you do not want to have a value like $103.56883264 lying about to be used in later in the process calculations. Since you might forget to use a rounding formula on it, or not want to, you need some other way to force the permanent change to $103.57 (or $103.56) that would then be cleanly used later.

In any case, to set this feature for use, you need to go to `File | Options | Advanced` and scroll down to almost the bottom. It is in the fourth grouping from the bottom, one called `When calculating this workbook:`, the second option in it. Just check that checkbox and it's good to go.

If you are competent in VBA, I recommend you handle this using it. If not, this would be a trivial thing for someone to write for you and would not seem like it should cost much. Or someone might do like in the other answer and write it for free. But if "PAD" is fine for the whole spreadsheet, it does this like a champ.

Now the thought I mentioned.

You seem to have this need because the information is exported to a different system "that you use." That is important and even more so in light of the idea that it sounds like you are THE user for this purpose, not supplying users with the export or them exporting it themselves.

A very easy to do thing would be to have a worksheet in the spreadsheet that mirrors the data you want exported. So you'd keep everything else the same as now and work with it just like now, and you'd do whatever you do to organize the export that you do now (maybe sort the data, delete some, whatever:  you'd get to the point where the very next step would be to perform the export in exactly the same way you do now).

Then you'd go to the mirror page and it should be set up to show the exact same data and arrangement of it that the place you would have normally exported from does.

With ONE exception. For the column of data on the mirror page showing this ID Number, instead of simply "=Sheet1!A1:A10000" you'd use the `TEXT()` function to force the desired format on that column. The original data would remain as it was, with the decimal portion, but the about-to-be-exported data on the mirror page would be utterly the rounded integer with absolutely no decimal portion. So the formula might look like:

```
=TEXT(  Sheet1!A1:A10000,  "0"  )
```

or whatever exact format you like though that one will do exactly this.

You then do the export from the mirror page so the integer ID Number will be what is exported.

(For your own comfort when checking to see if everything is there, you could `Copy` a row of the original data, then come here and select the range, then use `Paste | Special | Formats (and even column widths to make it reallllly look the same)` to make the formatting identical.)

If you are not the sole user in this spreadsheet it just makes it more complicated as you must deal with the other users' skills and comfort levels. And at some point, they could overwhelm the idea and leave you out of luck. You'd have to judge that, of course, if there are other users before the export. But if they only come after the export, in the other program, not in this spreadsheet, you can use the approach to solve the problem very easily and very cleanly.